# What is the surname of Brienne?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I realize that this seems like a ridiculous question, because Brienne's father is Lord Selwyn Tarth, and as his daughter she will be known as Brienne Tarth.

But in every single reference I have found to her she is known as Brienne **of** Tarth. Even searching on the [wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brienne_of_Tarth) for Brienne Tarth redirected me to Brienne of Tarth.

This makes no sense. I know that the island that she was born on is called Tarth, which I'm assuming is where her family name comes from, so this title makes sense (like *Sansa of Winterfell* for example). But why is the **of** *always* included?

She is the heir to Evenfall Hall, so she does by all accounts hold the name (she isn't a bastard), so why is she never referred to as Brienne Tarth? Is this even her name?

Comment: This sounds like a question for GRRM at a convention. I'd be interested to hear what he says but I imagine it'll be that he liked the sound it better. Brienne Tarth, the words kinda flow into each other. Selwyn Tarth, the emphasis on the n breaks it up better.

Comment: In medieval times, "Brienne of Tarth" and "Brienne Tarth" are pretty much the same thing. That's where modern last names come from.

Comment: Omegacron is correct that the two forms are identical, but it's a bit odd that she's *never* addressed as "Brienne Tarth". I can't think of another noble woman in the series that happens to...

Comment: Looks like it's not a lady of a small island thing [Maege Mormont](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maege_Mormont) is known as the "Lady of Bear Island", and she doesn't use an "of" in her name.

Comment: @MikeyMouse "Mormont" is not an island, though. "Lady *of* Bear Island" does have an "of" in it.

Comment: I'm not convinced "Sansa of Winterfell" would make sense. Winterfell is a castle, not a land/fiefdom like Tarth is. Sansa Stark, Sansa of Stark, Sansa of House Stark; those make sense. But Sansa of Winterfell doesn't sound like a proper feudal name...

Comment: If we pretend her middle name is "of" it all makes sense.

Comment: There are many such names, mostly related to nobility, such as `af`, `de`, `von`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Brienne is a character of unique circumstances within the world of ASoIaF. She is the daughter of a noble house, true, but is also trying to distance herself from that nobility. In addition, she is AFAIK the only example of a female knight in Westeros. These two factors together make her identity and naming somewhat unusual.

On the one hand, you are correct - her surname, as member of a minor house, is "Brienne Tarth". However, she seems to prefer being known as simply a knight from the island of Tarth. Under those circumstances, the name "Brienne of Tarth" would be more appropriate.

Brienne's father, Lord Selwyn Tarth, has also been known to use "Lord Selwyn of Tarth", so Brienne may also have chosen her name with that in mind.

**Note:** Since Brienne has not been formally knighted, she is unable to use the formal title of ***Ser***, assuming that ***Ser*** would even apply to a woman. Despite this, she identifies herself as a knight and lives her life accordingly.

Comment: I thought Renly knighted her and put her in his Kingsguard? Do people not consider that valid?

Comment: This makes sense. It is just unfortunate circumstance that her surname of Tarth happens to also be the name of the place that she is from. It surprises me though that at formal functions, like Joffrey and Margaery's wedding, that no one referred to her by her actual full name of "Brienne Tarth".

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield : I don't think she was ever knighted, just added to Renly's Kingsguard (which, officially, was never a legitimate organization). In the books she wasn't, but don't remember what happened on the show.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, The Hound was made a member of Jeoffrey's Kingsbuard, despite not being a knight.

Comment: Saying she prefers to be known as a knight is problematic. From "A Feast of Crows", chapter 14, Brienne's POV: 'He is still no squire, she reminded herself, but I am no knight, no matter how many times he calls me "ser."'. From memory, I think she also tries to distant herself from the idea of being a knight on the TV series.

Comment: @VitorDeMario you are correct. I meant "knight" in the more generic sense, as that is how people perceive her. And although she would be the first to correct someone, she DOES live as though she were already knighted. It is her aspiration & goal to make it official.

Comment: @Omegacron: Your point is valid. She behaves like a knight, lives like a knight, has been part of a Kingsguard. The only thing lacking is the title which is clearly a painful subject for her.

Comment: She's the person most befitting the title of knight in all of the series, yet is denied the title because of ancient custom. Fitting, given the kind of series ASoIaF is.

Comment: Just to confirm another relative is referred to as "Ser Endrew Tarth", he is a member of the Night's Watch.

Answer (score 8):

In the appendix to one of the books she's listed as such:

> BRIENNE OF TARTH, the Blue, also called BRIENNE THE BEAUTY, daughter
>   to Lord Selwyn the Evenstar

Her father is likewise listed as:

> LORD SELWYN OF TARTH, called the EVENSTAR

Tarth isn't a last name as we would define such a thing today, it's a place, and it's where she's from, and where her family's seat is.  So saying she's of that place is a normal styling in the medieval-ish definitions in use in the books.

(I'm not sure which book these entries are from, because I'm searching through the 5-book Google Books edition which mashes them together a little forcefully, but I suspect it's Storm of Swords).

Comment: Tarth is his House Name, so it is his surname. Other members of the family are identified as, e.g. "Quentyn Tarth". Also, note that Ned is *formally* Eddard of House Stark, so either is correct.

Comment: Okay.  It's a medieval surname, which is different than a modern surname.  But if you're at that point, then you shouldn't be noticing the words "OF" or "THE" in names because it's all medieval-y goodness.

Comment: I think the point is that other women are not called "Sansa of Stark", or "Cersei of Lannister", or "Ashara of Dayne", so why is Brienne "Brienne of Tarth"?

Comment: You're trying to regularize a system which led to someone being called "Garth the Gross"?  That's a little logocentric of you.

Comment: I dunno what regularize means here. I'm trying to point out IMO, there in a factual mistake in your answer. You claim Tarth is a place, and not a surname, while in fact, it's both, and that this makes the *in-universe* forms of address for noble ladies inconsistent for reasons that this answer doesn't really address.

Comment: And I'm pointing out that your expectation that naming systems are expected to be consistent and straightforward is based in a modern mindset and does not reflect either real-world history or the manufactured world of the books.

Comment: "My lady of Stark" has been used to address Arya at one point in the books. I think it was Jaqen who said it.

Comment: @gowenfawr I agree with you we can't expect faux-medieval names to be always consistent. *However*, your answer is wrong when it claims "Tarth isn't a last name, it's a place". This is wrong, because it's clearly *both*, and here GRRM is informed by real-life feudal customs. In the end, Brienne Tarth and Brienne *of* Tarth are equivalent, and GRRM probably chose the latter because it sounded better to him. Who knows?

Comment: "Things aren't consistent, too bad" is not a real answer either.

Comment: @MatthewRead well... it *could* be a real answer, if you could show evidence that the books are generally not consistent. In this specific case, my contention is that they *are* consistent for everyone else except Brienne, so I think there's a higher burden on anyone wanting to use that answer.

Comment: To what does her title "the Blue" refer?

Comment: @maguirenumber6, that's a reference to the color assigned to her as a member of Renly's "Rainbow Guard" (his LGBT version of the all-white "Kingsguard")

Answer (score 0):

This is actually extremely common, to be named after the place where you're from.  At the end of the medieval period when the middle class came into being, people started choosing last names, and that was also partly because the population was growing beyond the tiny villages that dotted the landscape. (Oh, and the Poll Tax) Many chose last names from their trade - Smith or Harper would be examples.

But my surname comes from a town in Scotland, for example. And the practice is more common in France, where you see more than a few names like DeBusey, DuPont, and De La Grange.